# Does this conjecture imply the prime number theorem?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-functions

### Background

I had asked on a forum if my conjecture was of any value:

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty}  \lim_{n \to \infty}\ \sum_{r=1}^n d_r \left(  f\left(\frac{rk}{n}\right)\frac{k}{n} \right) =  \lim_{s \to 1} \! \underbrace{\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}   \sum_{r=1}^\infty  \frac{d_r}{r^s}}_{\text{removable singularity}} \int_{0^+}^\infty f(x) \, dx  $$

Where $f(x)$ is a smooth continuous function whose integral $\int_0^\infty f(x) d x  $ is absolutely convergent. $d_r$ is the $r$-th number of an arbitrary sequence.

One of the commentor's said:

> ... For example for $d_r=\log(p)$ if $ r=p^k$ and $d_r=0$ if $r$ is not a prime power (the Von Mangoldt function) your formula is a famous theorem: the prime number theorem ....

He didn't give any further hints.

### Question

Can someone elaborate on how this implies the PNT?

Comment: I would try writing the left-hand side as a [Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution). Note that the sums here are over divisors, which the Von-Mangoldt function being zero on composite numbers might help you manipulate your sum into. Also note that $\sum_{r = 1}^\infty d_r/r^s$ is well-known for $d_r = \Lambda(r)$ being the von-mangoldt function --- it's $-\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$ (see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function#Dirichlet_series) for a citation).

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the PNT.

If $d_r \ge 0$ and $
\sum_{r \le y} d_r \sim ay$ and $f$ is continuous and $L^1$ then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n d_r  f\left(\frac{rk}{n}\right)\frac{k}{n} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n a  f\left(\frac{rk}{n}\right)\frac{k}{n} = a\int_0^k f(x)dx$$

On the other hand

$$\lim_{s \to 1^+} (s-1) \sum_{r=1}^\infty d_r r^{-s}=a$$

If $\sum_{r \le y} d_r = o(y)$ then both side converges to $0$, if $ y = o(\sum_{r \le y} d_r)$ then both side diverge to $\infty$.

If $\sum_{r \le y} d_r \sim ay$ you can use partial summation to remove the assumption $d_r \ge 0$